# getting blank pages for editing wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am managing this site: http://www.reurl.in/5a9b63301. It's a wordpress theme site and I need to edit some pages like the index page. But when I go to the wordpress admin panel, while editing the page it shows me a blank page without any code. And when I see the index page from ftp it shows me this code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
* Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
  */
 define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

 /** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
 require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

If you guys have any idea about this please let me know as this is very important for me. And also suggest anything that is important for me to understand for wordpress editing.

Comment: First of all, whatever you want to change, don't change core files. Create a child theme if it is not present already and make changes tot that. To solve the issue try disabling all plugins and see if the text comes back. If it does, switch plugins back on one by one to see where it stops working.

Answer (score 1):

First of all like already mentioned don't modify the core theme files as when the theme gets updated your files will be overwritten and it makes problems harder to debug.

First thing to do is turn on WP Debug on in wp-config.php:

Change this line:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );
```

To:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

You should then get an error on your screen and it will tell you where it's coming from (Plugin, theme files etc).